# How to capture video stream using emgu cv

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am doing my project about hand gesture recognition so, I want to capture video stream using web cam.

Currently I am using emgu cv wrapper for open cv image processing library.

any solution to capture video stream in to image?

My emgu cv version is 2.4.10

Thanks...

Comment: Have you found any other resources or options that you are choosing between? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to create Capture object then using that object call QueryFrame method it will provide RGB image

```
Capture videoCapture = new Capture();
Image<Bgr, byte> currentFrame = videoCapture.QueryFrame();
```

Happy Coding.....