# How to convert Capture to Image<Bgr,Byte> using Emgu library

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I am struggling to covert Capture into Image using Emgu libraries in C#. I know that there are examples of code on Emgu website, but these don't involve camera capture. I want to get some processing done to the frames from camera.

This is what I have so far:

```
Capture capture = null;
capture = new Capture(); //create a camera capture
capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.Fps, 30);
capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameHeight, 240);
capture.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CapProp.FrameWidth, 320); 
viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame()
viewer.ShowDialog();
```

I would like to be able to use capture in the following line:

```
Image<Gray, Byte> gray = capture.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
```

Thank you

Comment: Just to update I have used [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988892/how-to-capture-video-stream-using-emgu-cv)

but when I try to rebuild it complains that **Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Mat' to 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you have a Mat and you want an Image you could do the following:

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(theMat.Bitmap);
```

Doug

Comment: Thank you! In addition I found that the following line does the job too:
`Capture capture2 = new Capture();`
`Mat capMat= capture2.QueryFrame();`
`Image<Bgr, byte> image = capMat.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();`